# Not able to get paperclip to upload images using devise to update user profile photo in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, activerecord, paperclip

I am trying to implement paperclip to allow users to update their profile image on their account. I am using devise for account creation and update but I'm a little unsure about how devise works with paperclip in order to save the image to ActiveRecord. Paperclip will allow me to select a photo and submit it but the photo will not display when I go to the show view. I am not sure if devise is saving it to active record accordingly or what the problem may be so after spending way to many hours on this feature I am coming to the StackOverflow community for help. Please help me!

users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:image)
end

end
```

registrations_controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

private

def sign_up_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
:password_confirmation)
end

def account_update_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :image, 
:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end

end
```

edit.html.erb (devise registration view)

```
<%= form_for (resource, as: resource_name, url: 
registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.file_field :image %>
</div>
...
```

user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :appointments
has_many :fruits, dependent: :destroy
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { large: "150x150>", medium: 
"100x100>", thumb: "50x50#"}
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: 
/\Aimage\/.*\Z/

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

show view:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "user" %>

<h1><%= @user.name %></h1>

<div class="pic">
<%= image_tag @user.image.url(:large) %>
</div>

<h4>Phone: <%= @user.phone %></h4>
<h4>Email: <%= @user.email %></h4>

<p> 
<%= link_to "Edit Info", edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %> 
</p>
```

Comment: Update your question with your user model code

Comment: Can you please also show us the code for how you have your "show" view written? Also investigate if anything related to the image is being persisted into the database

Comment: Just updated. What do you think could be the issue

Comment: Are you sure the image is persisted to the DB? can you confirm?

Comment: image not adding in db

Comment: image_file_name, image_content_type, and image_file_size all say nil

Comment: also what if the image uploaded is a jpeg?

Comment: Ok so like my answer stated you need to add `image` to your `sign_up_params`. If the image is jpeg just replace the `format` by jpeg. simple

Comment: did that work??

Comment: What I was asking is what if I need both jpg and jpeg to be able to be uploaded. Can I do something like this? 

    <%= image_tag attachment_url(@user, :image, :fill, 300, 300, format: 
    "jpeg, jpg") %>

Comment: Now I'm getting 

undefined method `attachment_url'

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you'd do it:

First create a migration in your User model:

```
class AddAvatarToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_attachment :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

Second in your User model add the necessary attachment:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/default_image.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Then make sure you are permitting the `avatar` parameter:

```
def sign_up_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, 
:password_confirmation, :avatar)
end

def account_update_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :image, 
:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :avatar)
end
```

And finally, add field to upload the picture:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: users_path, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**:

To fully answer your question this is how you'd display the image in your show.html.erb file:

Instead of:

```
<%= image_tag @user.image.url(:large) %>
```

do:

```
<%= image_tag attachment_url(@user, :image, :fill, 300, 300, format: "jpeg") %>
```

Comment: is the problem about displaying the picture?

Comment: I appreciate the response and the willingness to help. I really do. But because it seems that you are failing to either read or comprehend the information that I have posted, I'm going to politely ask that you defer any further response or solution to this question. Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to help so no need for those type of comments. Thanks